# How to make the Admin interface language switch based on node content?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

How can I make the Administration interface language be the same as the Editing content?

By example. If I edit a French content, I would like my interface in French.
If I edit an English content, I would like my interface in English.

Answer (score 1):

On D7 you'll find a language **detection and selection** page at `admin/config/regional/language/configure`:

[image]

If you enable and put "**URL** Determine the language from the URL (Path prefix or domain)" on top the system will show the interface in French for nodes (and other content) in French and it will be English for English content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Admin Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language) module? Otherwise by default the interface and everything should be according the current chosen language.

`Administration Language` module lets the administrator see all administration pages in her preferred language. It is used to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).

Other than this you may check if you have imported the translation packages for your language from https://localize.drupal.org/translate for the required languages. It will provide the translation for most of the strings.

For installing the translation for all the languages you may give a try to [localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module: Automatically download and update your translations fetching them from localize.drupal.org or any other Localization server.